# Compile ffprobe linux library

Tags: linux, ffprobe

Is it possible to compile ffprobe in linux as a library (ffprobe.so)?
Couldn't find nothing on google about it.
If yes, any references on how the library can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ffprobe is a command-line tool, not a library; it's a relatively thin wrapper around libavformat/libavcodec. If you want a library, use those directly.

[Here's the full source code to ffprobe.](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/ffprobe.c) It's a bit long, as it can print a **lot** of information about some file formats, but it shouldn't be too hard for you to pick out the bits that you care about.